# OpenCL and C++: events not working properly

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm very lost, but luckily I narrowed the problem to a few lines of code.

I'm defining a class that stores events as pointers in member `std::vector<cl::Event*> m_lastaccesses`. In call to `operator=` between class instances `A` and `B`, `enqueueWriteBuffer` is called with `blockingWrite` set to `CL_FALSE` and `A.m_lastaccesses[0]` as its return event. Before exiting `operator=` this event is copied with `*B.m_lastaccesses[1]=*A.m_lastaccesses[0]`, and `operator=` is exited.

If I change `CL_FALSE` to `CL_TRUE` **or** call `A.m_lastaccesses[0]->wait()` before exiting `operator=` the host effectively waits for the data transfer and everything works fine. If I instead leave `CL_FALSE` and call `A.m_lastaccesses[0]->wait()` **right after** exiting `operator=` the host doesn't wait, even though I verify that `A.m_lastaccesses[0]` points to the same memory address as before.

My conjecture is that some reference count works unexpectedly and `cl::Event` is freed or modified by OpenCL's C++ wrapper

Comment: It's really hard to pinpoint without seeing your code. You store events as raw pointers, who takes care of the allocation/deallocation? Seems `std::unique_ptr` could be useful here.
From the documentation, `cl::Event::wait()` blocks until the event completes. Are you sure the event wasn't completed? On a side note, this C++ wrapper seems more complicated than its C counterpart...

Comment: Indeed I feel like the C++ wrapper is lacking.

The sole purpose of storing them as raw pointer was to signal with NULL whenever there wasn't any event of a certain kind, since I couldn't manage to init non-pointer events to dummy `CL_COMPLETE` events, so I made sure to deallocate them in the destructor and only use them through dereference.

Sadly, I solved the problem by rewriting the code (wasn't long) and reestructuring it a bit, so I don't know what's actually going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So... you have a vector of **pointers:**

> `std::vector<cl::Event*> m_lastaccesses`

... and you're copying pointer **contents:**

> `*B.m_lastaccesses[1]=*A.m_lastaccesses[0]`

... how do you know `B.m_lastaccesses[1]` is a valid pointer ? If it is a valid pointer, what happens to the instance stored there when that line of code overwrites it ? Is this the actual code, because i'm surprised it works at all...

> My conjecture is that some reference count works unexpectedly

Perhaps. My conjecture is that you're messing with pointers and pointer contents, and somewhere it blows up. And i don't really see a good reason to use pointers here; i'd simply store cl::Event objects directly. The classes in cl2.hpp usually only store a single pointer to the underlying CL object, copying/deleting them is cheap (only results in clRetain/clRelease) and you can avoid even those clRetain/clRelease calls with move-assignments. In a way, cl::Event acts as a "smart" pointer.

Oh, and you can always take a look at cl2.hpp source. It's not that complicated.

Comment: Given `B.m_lastaccesses[1]` is properly allocated, `*B.m_lastaccesses[1]=*A.m_lastaccesses[0]` will simply invoke `cl::Event.operator=`, just as if I called `eventA=eventB` without pointers. I'm assuming if it is defined, the C++ wrapper deals with that operation properly.
The actual code is of course longer and takes the proper measures to guarantee event pointers are allocated when needed and freed when the class is destroyed.